# Unclear behavior of the defun macro

Tags: elisp

Good afternoon. The defun macro places the procedure code in the functional cell of the symbol and, if no errors are found, prints the name of the symbol in the mini-buffer.

```
(defun InsertSsulku ()
"Вставка текста ссылки на якорь-ноду в точку"
(interactive)
(let* ((karta '(keymap "Вставка ссылок"
               ("Решения" menu-item "Решения"
            (keymap "Решения"
                ("@ref{сбрнкФйлвРквдств, текст-ссылки}" menu-item "@anchor{сбрнкФйлвРквдств}" fint-function :key-sequence nil)))
               ("Скрипты" menu-item "Скрипты"
            (keymap "Скрипты"
                ("@ref{Родительский скрипт, текст ссылки}" menu-item "@anchor{Родительский скрипт}" fint-function :key-sequence nil)
                ("@ref{Дочерний скрипт, текст ссылки}" menu-item "@anchor{Дочерний скрипт}" fint-function :key-sequence nil)))))
       (выбзнч (x-popup-menu (list '(0 0) (selected-frame))            
           karta)))                                       
  (insert (nth (- (length выбзнч) 1) выбзнч))))
```

The next question is, why does the procedure begin to run when defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The next question is, why does the procedure begin to run when defined?

It doesn't.  What do you mean by that?

Comment: When a period is in the text of the procedure definition, the input "ctrl+al+x" starts the execution of the device

Comment: Provide an example of that in your question, then, plus a recipe for reproducing the issue, and be sure to detail *specifically* what's happening that is unexpected.

Comment: Thank you. Probably some other forms influenced. In a clean buffer, *scratch* works as expected. We need to remove the issue.